# SQLite Query to group continuous range of numbers into different grouping sets

Tags: sqlite

I want get the islands of this table below:

```
Group    MemberNo
A           100
A           101
A           200
A           201
A           202
A           203
X           100
X           101
A           204
X           301
X           302
A           500
A           600
```

I want get this results using SQL (the islands):

```
Group  FromMemberNo      ToMemberNo
A             100             101
A             200             204
X             100             101
X             301             302
A             500             500
A             600             600
```

I have seen a lot of codes/forums for this but not working with SQLite because SQLite doesn't have CTEs.

100-101 is continuous so that it will be group into one.

Does anyone know how to do it in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to do this would be to go through the ordered records of this table in a loop and collect the islands manually.

In pure SQL (as a set-oriented language), this is not so easy.

First, we find out which records are the first in an island. The first record does not have a previous record, i.e., a record with the same group but with a `MemberNo` one smaller:

```sql
SELECT "Group",
       MemberNo AS FromMemberNo
FROM ThisTable AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ThisTable AS t2
                  WHERE t2."Group" = t1."Group"
                    AND t2.MemberNo = t1.MemberNo - 1)
```

To find the last record of an island, we have to find the record with the largest `MemberNo` that still belongs to the same island, i.e., has the same group, and where all `MemberNo`s in the island are continuous.
We detect continuous `MemberNo`s by computing the difference between their values in the first and last records.
The last `MemberNo` of the island with group `G` and first `MemberNo` `M` can be computed like this:

```sql
SELECT MAX(MemberNo) AS LastMemberNo
FROM ThisTable AS t3
WHERE t3."Group" = G
  AND t3.MemberNo - M + 1 = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                             FROM ThisTable AS t4
                             WHERE t4."Group" = G
                               AND t4.MemberNo BETWEEN M AND t3.MemberNo)
```

Finally, plug this into the first query:

```sql
SELECT "Group",
       MemberNo AS FromMemberNo,
       (SELECT MAX(MemberNo)
        FROM ThisTable AS t3
        WHERE t3."Group" = t1."Group"
          AND t3.MemberNo - t1.MemberNo + 1 = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                               FROM ThisTable AS t4
                                               WHERE t4."Group" = t1."Group"
                                                 AND t4.MemberNo BETWEEN t1.MemberNo AND t3.MemberNo)
       ) AS LastMemberNo
FROM ThisTable AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ThisTable AS t2
                  WHERE t2."Group" = t1."Group"
                    AND t2.MemberNo = t1.MemberNo - 1)
```